# Parsing XML with lxml.objectify.Getting error

Tags: html, xml, lxml, lxml.objectify

The following code is from 'Python for Data Analysis':

```
from io import StringIO
import io

tag = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>'
root = objectify.parse(io.StringIO(tag).getroot())
```

Executing the code produces the following error:

```
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`StringIO` expects a unicode string which is not the default kind of string in python 2.
Replacing

```
tag = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>'
```

with

```
tag = u'<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>'
```

should work.